# Application and invalid certificate errors

Tags: twilio

I am testing a call flow and I am receiving the following errors.
I am receiving this error message on my twilio alert dashboard:

> 11237 - Certificate Invalid - Could not find path to certificate

and if I try dialing the number the prompt I hear on the phone is

> We are sorry and application error has occurred. Goodbye

I am using a trial account and have not upgraded yet. I am also using openvbx.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Hi, could you please add more information to the question regarding the programming language you're using and some of your code? Thanks

Comment: i have no codes to show since all of this is done through the openvbx dashboard. im wondering if i missed something on the settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting is documented here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11237

So, you either configure the phone number *'Request URL'* value at Twilio to use http instead of https or configure your openvbx web server (Apache or Nginx) with a certificate from an established CA (certificate authority), that means you can't use a self signed certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here. I think the error you're seeing is because you're either trying to use a self-signed certificate, or the certificate you're using is not issued by an approved certificate authority.

Check [this link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11237) out for more information.

If you want to use SSL, I would suggest using something like [let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). I wrote [an article](https://www.placona.co.uk/1535/general-techie-stuff/how-to-secure-apache-with-lets-encrypt-and-cloudflare-on-centos/) describing how to install it on Apache.

Hope this helps you