# Twilio SSL Validation - Error 11237

Tags: validation, certificate, twilio

I am relating to [Application and invalid certificate errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37249582/application-and-invalid-certificate-errors)

When i initiate the call with Twilio REST API, and then pick up the phone, i can hear that error occured and [Certificate Invalid - Could not find path to certificate](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11237) appears in my alert dashboard.

However, certificate is located in the mozila certificate program, i can find certificate at [Public All Intermediate Certs List](https://ccadb-public.secure.force.com/mozilla/PublicAllIntermediateCerts). I dont use self signed certificate.

As soon as i disable **SSL Certificate Validation** inside Twilio Console Account settings, the problem is gone.

> **My result from qualys ssl lab are:**

**Summary:**

1. This server is vulnerable to the POODLE attack. If possible, disable SSL 3 to mitigate. Grade capped to C.
2. This server accepts RC4 cipher, but only with older protocols. Grade capped to B.
3. The server does not support Forward Secrecy with the reference browsers.
4. This server's certificate chain is incomplete. Grade capped to B.

---

**Configuration:**

1. SSL 3 *INSECURE*

---

**Cipher Suites:**

1. TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xa) *WEAK*
2. TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x16)   DH 4096 bits   FS   *WEAK*
3. TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc012)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   *WEAK*
4. TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x5)   *INSECURE*
5. TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc011)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   *INSECURE*

---

**Protocol details:**

1. Secure Renegotiation    *Supported*
2. POODLE (SSLv3)  Vulnerable   *INSECURE*    SSL 3: 0xa
3. Downgrade attack prevention *Yes*, TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV supported
4. RC4 Yes   *INSECURE*
5. Forward Secrecy With some browsers

---

Shall i disable SSL or do you have any ideas what can i do?

Comment: Can you run your URL through https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and edit your question with the results?

Comment: Done, please let me know if my edit is enough for you or you need more complex details from qualys results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I am hoping that your https://ssllabs.com/ssltest has scared you sufficiently enough. You need to upgrade your server from SSLv3 to TLS as SSLv3 and a lot more of your setup is insecure and will not protect you in the face of an attack.

[Twilio has deprecated support for SSLv3 and supports TLS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/security#encrypted-communication). This is likely why you are getting an invalid certificate error.

For the sake of your and your users own security and safety, please upgrade your server.